# Where to store dynamic connection string in provider-hosted app?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-addin, database-connection

I have a Sharepoint 2013 provider-hosted app that gets installed (along with a custom WCF Sharepoint-hosted service) using a powershell script.
This script also creates a SQL Server database that the app uses to store some data. After the database is created, an sql login and user is created and a connection string is generated.

The question is, where to store this connection string so the app can get it?

Since is kind of sensitive information, I'd like a place that's only accessible via server-side code.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up storing it in the Site collection property bag.

Answer (score 3):

You can programmatically add/update AppSettings to the web.config file.  You could store your connection string in an AppSetting string...

Comment: Yes but the script that creates the database is a powershell script. And it runs before the app is installed, so there's no web.config...

Answer (score 0):

For SharePoint 2010 and up, you can actually store your credentials in the Secure Store Service, then programatically access as needed using the SharePoint Object Model.

Here is a link including instructions on how to achieve this:
[CLICK HERE](http://blog.metrostarsystems.com/2013/03/13/storing-connection-string-information-in-the-secure-store-service/)

Comment: I don't think that's going to work in a provider hosted app. The code from the link includes things like SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges which is clearly not available in a Sharepoint App.